# Is there any way to concatenate tuples with a maximum lenght?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm concatenating three tuples from a csv but i´m thinking if there is any way to do it with a maximum lenght.
I´m doing this:

```
df = pd.read_csv(FILE_NAME, header = 0)
df['all'] = df['Header'] + df['Subtitle'] + df['Text']
```

I want df['all] to be at most 500 characters

Thank you in advice

Comment: Why not just post-process `df['all']` at the end? `df['all'] = df['all'].str[:500]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can slice the concatenation:

```
df['all'] = (df['Header'] + df['Subtitle'] + df['Text']).str[:500]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `df.head()` function to get the first rows of a dataframe:

```py
df = pd.read_csv(FILE_NAME, header = 0)
df_short = df.head(500)
df_short['all'] = df_short['Header'] + df_short['Subtitle'] + df_short['Text']
```

Comment: How does it answer the question?

Comment: df_short["all"] would have the concats of the columns for the first 500 rows, which is what I belive you were asking for?

Comment: The OP is asking about the content length, not number of rows.

Comment: Ah ok! Makes sense. In that case, @mozway's answer should work.